# Why is Core Data Model URL (modelURL) returning as nil?

Tags: ios, core-data

When I create a new project with CoreDataModel created by XCode, all is well.  However, I added a core model file to my project and the "core data stack" code.  The code is properly getting invoked, however, the model's URL is nil.  I have tried to examine the project and cannot determine if the model file is not properly added, or compiled, or if the URL just cannot be found.

Help me debug and resolve.

```
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Model" withExtension:@"momd"];
```

modelUrl returns as `nil`.

Comment: What's the name of your model?

Comment: @KyleEmmanuel the model name is Model.xcdatamodeld  When I created the model, I named it Model.

Comment: Is your model included in your build phases->compile sources?

Comment: @mobibob you can get some ides from here: http://craig24.com/2014/12/how-to-add-core-data-to-an-existing-swift-project-in-xcode/

Answer (score 2):

Check for correct names, then click on the `Model.momd` file in the file inspector on the left. In the file attributes inspector on the right make sure it is added to the correct target you are running (i.e. the checkmark beside your target name is checked).

If you cannot find the file in the first place, you have not added it to the bundle correctly. Drag it from the Finder window into your project.

Another hint: note that the there are always at least two files: the directory and the model(s) inside. But you cannot see that if there is only one model version.

```
Model.xcdatamodeld
    Model.xcdatamodel
```

Make sure that both files in the Finder have the same name before adding the directory to your project. (The directory will show up as a single file.)

Comment: I don't see any .momd files for CoreDataStack nor for my project.  I deleted (references) and dragged back-in from Finder.  Same problem.  What I noticed in the debugger for CoreDataStack the .momd file shows up underneath the CoreDataStack.app instance of the debugger folder.  I do not show the same for my project.

Comment: The files show as `.xcdatamodeld` in Xcode and in the Finder.

Comment: The xcdatamodeld has always shown up.  When stepping through the default core-stack project, the file with .momd is expanded and it is relative to the .app file (this makes sense).  In my project where I added a model.xcdatamodeld to the project, it is always nil.  I suspect it is either the "relativeness" of the path, or the reference is not getting into the build scripts.  There isn't any information in the Apple forums nor generically on the web that I can find that would indicate that this is a problem for anyone else :(

Comment: Just delete it from he project and drag it into the project window in again, making sure it is properly copied if necessary and added to the right targets. I just tried it and it works. Double-check the **name** as well.

Comment: Check out the additional info I added to the answer.

Comment: Hi all -- I did visit all the recommended answers, documentation, etc.  Everything (visible) in project configuration were set as you all suggested, but eventually, the only way I got it to work was to create a new project and port-over the code.  Thank goodness, I was at the beginning of the project.  I have always suspected that there is some "hook-up reference" buried in the XML that is not getting inserted.  -- I may never know.  Thank you all for your help.

Comment: I voted up the comments.  The answer did not answer, so I didn't want to vote up -- I guess I just don't accept the answer. +1